# android studio how to convert field to local variable automatically

Tags: android-studio, field, local-variables

Occasionally one might run into a "Field can be converted to a local variable" warning in Android Studio (AS). Is there a way to do have this conversion done automatically by AS?

Comment: I can only come up with `Alt - Enter` on the highlighted element, but that just brings up the context menu wherein you can select the action that should be taken. (taken from here http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/IntelliJ.html#link_2)

Comment: what is the significance of this warning? I mean how problematic can it be from performance or memory use aspect , if left unhandled..?

Answer (score 4):

Android Studio has added that option in the meantime (I have version 1.5.1). When you run Analyze/Inspect Code, you have "Field can be local" under Class structure section, and when you click on that issue in the left pane, in the right pane you are offered a link "Convert to local", which does it automagically.